# Looking for a proof of a dominated convergence theorem for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: probability-theory, integration, stochastic-calculus

From what I've read there exists a similar theorem to the dominated convergence theorem for Lebesgue integrals, which is applicable to Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals.

Does someone have a statement of this theorem and if possible a proof for me? I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Comment: Aren't Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals Lebesgue integrals by definition?

Comment: I thought that was only for continuous functions.

Comment: The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration#Definition) defines Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals of bounded, Borel-measurable functions as a finite sum of Lebesgue integrals.